# What is the complexity of an algorithm: T (n) = 3 * T (n ÷ b) + n² + 1?

Tags: algorithm, math, time-complexity, complexity-theory, recurrence

What is the complexity of an algorithm: T (n) = 3 * T (n ÷ b) + n² + 1?
Ask a question

one

Can you help me know what is the complexity of: T (n) = 3 * T (n ÷ b) + n² + 1. When n> 1 ?.

I have been trying to understand a little the master method for the calculation of algorithmic complexities since I have to make a school presentation solving this problem, but I have not been able to solve it well. If you can advise me, I would value it a lot.

Thank you!

Comment: Assume b > 1, too, right? Otherwise is never converges.  But what is T(n) for n<=1? Constant? Assume it is ... so each time you increase n by a factor of b you add one iteration ... (the rest of the equation doesn't matter, you are just looking for how many times it executes as n increases).

Comment: O(n^3) i guessed, not sure. Every stack of function runs complexity of n^2 untill condition end(maybe n is zero or less than a mysterious number). and this will be done n times( n / b is same O(n) as it expressed time complexity).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If b equals 1, the critical coefficient of the master is undefined and the regularity condition is not satisfied. T(n) fails to be well-defined at all in that case and does not have any reasonable solutions.

If b equals 2, the critical coefficient of the master theorem is log_2(3) and n^log_2(3) = O(n^2)… also, because T(n) satisfies regularity in this case, the Master theorem tells us the complexity here is O(n^2).

Indeed, for any b greater than 2, the above analysis applies as well: log_b(3) is always less than 2 for integers b greater than 1. For any such choice, regularity will be satisfied, so we are always in case 3 of the Master theorem and have that T(n) = O(n^2).